# Runtime Error occurs when require('electron') with Jest test file

Tags: node.js, electron, jestjs

When I `import 'electron'` and run Jest, following error occurs. Using `require` or `import` don't matter.
And `jest.autoMockOff()` doesn't help also.

```
 FAIL  __tests__/root_test.js
● Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

Versions are as follows.

- node: v4.2.1
- jest-cli: v0.8.2
- electron-prebuilt: v0.36.4

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How are you running JestJS?

Comment: I write `"scripts": {"test": "jest"}` into package.json and running with `npm test`.
And my npm version is 2.14.7

Comment: As a workaround, I moved `const remote = require('electron').remote;` from top of the file into function, and the tests passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tests load built-in Electron modules you have to run them within an Electron process, built-in Electron modules are not available in a regular Node process (which is what you get if you just run `jest` from the commandline).

Comment: Oh thank you, that makes sense.

But actually, I'm using `remote` module in a React component and want to test it. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I don't think there's any ready-made solution for JestJS, but you can roll your own if Jest can be used as a library. If you were using Mocha I'd say look at https://github.com/jprichardson/electron-mocha or https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare (depending on what you want to test).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `modulePathIgnorePatterns` in package.json

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#config-modulepathignorepatterns-array-string